# Which framework is useful for Website development using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks

I am new to website development. Currently I am developing website using PHP and MySQL.

Why I need to use framework for developing application? Which framework is useful for website developing using PHP, MySQL? When it will help because using framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons to use frameworks is pretty simple.

1. Most of the bloat is already written (security, database components, routing etc.).
2. There are hundreds of people "testing and updating the framework everyday"
3. Writing code is much cleaner and formatted

There are a lot of frameworks.

It depends on your needs.

I recently started using Laravel 5 and I am inlove.

Some others as well

1. Yii
2. Yii2
3. Symphony
4. PHPCake
5. Zend
6. CodeIgniter